# Make Ubuntu automatically force reboot before fully loading

Tags: boot, bootloader, reboot

I have an ACPI problem which means I need to boot into Ubuntu and reboot into Windows. The BIOS can't turn ACPI off or otherwise be configured to solve it.

Is there a way to make Ubuntu automatically load and restart itself?  If there's some way to make Ubuntu load first > automatically restart as soon as the kernel is loaded > make Windows load as a one-off first, it would solve my problem.

How could I find that?

Comment: Thank you for the reply mate. But there is no option o turn off ACPI as the bios is very limited.

Comment: "The BIOS can't turn ACPI off or otherwise be configured to solve it." that seems odd. what is brand and version of the BIOS? besides that: acpi can be turned off from grub options menu. also possible with windows.

Comment: If UEFI can you not directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu, often f10 or f12, same key you used to select to boot USB flash drive installer?

Comment: Its a Dell XPS 9343. It seems to have a known issue with drivers/firmware/bios/hardware for its sound card.

Comment: Can I use Grub boot parameters on Windows 10? I can boot directly fine into either OS, Its just that the audio chipset is a realtek alc3263 and it wont work in I2S mode (which my bios switches to when windows was the last booting OS). When Linux is the last booting OS, it switches to HDA audio and this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I can help you with your second question, but I may be able to help you with the first question. It's unfortunately not automatic, but you can hit alt+PrtSc, then while holding those two, type in this order R E I S U B (Busier backwards). This will force Ubuntu to reboot (safely).

Hope this helped,
sanserfio